# How to declare navigation graph in gradle

Tags: java, android, navigation

When I add navigation declaration in gradle.. On the time of lunching app following error is shown:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha05] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-21:19 to override.
```

Code in gradle which I have written by google-------------->:

```
def nav_version = "2.1.0-alpha01"

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

Declaring this in gradle crash my app

Answer (score 0):

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

Add Above lines in application tag in AndroidManifest